# Allow background activity by default in android

Tags: android

I am building an android app in android studio, but on my app by default allow background activity is restricted, I have service on my app though to allow push notifications to users even when app is closed, but after a very long time when the app is not opened it stops getting notification.

After I researched, I learned I need to enable foreground service, how do i allow this to enabled by default for my app
[image]

This enabled by default on many messaging apps, my app is also a messenger app for chat
[image]

Comment: WHat r you trying to do?

Comment: You can't.  That's on purpose, otherwise every app would just do it to avoid battery optimizations.  Instead, tell us what you actually want to do in the background, and we can probably tell you a better way to do it.

Comment: I want to add background activity for my app which permission will I use in my manifest to make this enabled by default

Comment: As for push notifications-  that's how they work by default.  They will wake up the app if the app is closed.  Unless you're trying to roll your own push notification method, in which case-  don't do that.

Comment: But I see this enabled by default for many apps like WhatsApp, koo, and many messaging app, my app is a messaging app and users will not they have new messages when app is killed in background, I checked other messaging apps including Facebook and it's enabled by default check the image I added to my question